# ZF2 How to get the excecuted query string from paginator

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I'm using the ZF2 paginator like so:

```
// Paginator config

$paginator_adapter = new DbSelect($select, $adapter);
$paginator = new Paginator($paginator_adapter);

$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

return $paginator;
```

How can I echo the built SQL query for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ZendDeveloperTools` : https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/zend-developer-tools-zf2-debug-toolbar-install/

> ZendDeveloperTools is a Module for developer and debug tools for
>   working with the ZF2 MVC layer. It can show you a request method,
>   response code, current controller/action, current route we access,
>   execution time, memory consumption, grab the profiler of Zend\Db
>   adapter instance, and Zend Framework version you currently use.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, thanks tho.

```
echo $select->getSqlString($adapter->getPlatform());
```